# Is there something similar to Twitter Bootstrap that uses Mustache templates?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, templates, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Looking for `HTML/CSS/Javascript` template for a Rails app, but one that uses Mustache templates.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.Use foundation zurb for more details visit  http://foundation.zurb.com/

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails/tree/master/vendor/twitter/docs/templates/pages there are some mustache templates in bootstrap-rails, but I haven't found something like mustache-bootstrap-rails. It's strange. Maybe it's a chance for you to do a useful gem or add mustache generators to bootstrap-rails :).